# Updating Shared prefrence after activity loads in Android

Tags: android

In this code value of the shared preference will be assigned after this activity is launched.I want this code to continuously listen to the change in the shared preference value and upon change an activity to trigger.But the code on execution throws an error saying Null pointer.

Thanks Varanasi

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.d_pay);
        con=dpay.this;
        sh=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("CRUZER_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);



        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }           
     @Override
     public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      autoUpdate = new Timer();
      autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
          updateHTML();
         }
        });
       }
      }, 0, 40000); // updates each 40 secs
     }

     private void updateHTML(){
         p=sh.getString("p", null);
Log.e("p", p);
      // your logic here
     }

     @Override
     public void onPause() {
      autoUpdate.cancel();
      super.onPause();
     }
```

Comment: Use a LocalBroadcastReceiver whenever you touch the SharedPreferences

Comment: You want this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

Comment: Any code sniippet with the Local Broad Cast receiver Pls..

Answer (score 0):

I think that having a timer that checks the preferences is a bit wasteful. Assuming that you have access to all the code that changes your SharedPreferences, what you can do is create a wrapper class around SharedPreferences, let's call it `PrefHelper`. In `PrefHelper` you'll have a method called `setMySpecificPref(context, your parameters here)`. Anywhere you need to change that preference, you call that method. That method will then change the preference and launch your desired activity.

Comment: Yes, you simply need to override [`onNewIntent(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) and your Activity will receive that new Intent. Note that you need to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in your manifest as the launch mode

Comment: can i ask you what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sure more context would be useful, go ahead!

Comment: Actually there are two activities.Now after the first activity loads there is a button click that happens in activity two which sets the shared preference value.Once the shared preference value is set I want an even triggered in activity one.But since activity one loads first it is giving me a null pointer exception.

Comment: If the activity isn't even visible when the preference changes, you could just ovverride `onResume()` of the first activity and update accordingly

Comment: NO actuially this is a two user application.It has two different logins.The second activity is on a different user and the first activity on the other.So the button click on second activity loads a event on first user.The first user will be waiting for the button click from second user